# Save Data in a Column Python DS18B20

Tags: python

My Python code for data saves data of a temperature sensor(DS18B20) but doesn't save the Temperature in a column. The Temperature is written in a line like that: ['25.25']. Can somebody please tell me how to fix it. I have to separate the read Temperature from the Sensor into several Numbers. Thanks for your help

```
    while programmStatus == 1:
    #while True:
            now = datetime.now(timezoneBerlin)
                
#while True:
    # open new file
            with open ( 'test.tsv', 'w') as f:
                for temperature_single in Temperature:
                    f.write ("{:>5}\n".format('Temperature'))    
                    f.write("\t{:>5}\n".format 
                    (format(temperature_single)))
                    f.write("\n")
                    f.flush()
                    f.close()
   
                x = 0
                ds1820readout()
                print ("Sensorname und Temperaturevalue:")
                while x < tempSensorQuantity:
                    print (tempSensorName[x] , " " , tempSensorValue[x], " °C")
                    x = x + 1
print ("\n")
```

In this code, there is an I/0 error on closed file, can somebody please help?

Comment: Please provide a very simple sample input and expected output, like [10.12, 12.15, 15.30] -> [10,12,30]

Comment: I will do this soon thanks

Comment: @Andreas I did this now and the Input (10.12, 12.15, 15.30) put in in the known code get the following output: 10.12 can anyone help me why its not write the next number in one line?

Comment: I would, but your question is unfortunately not really specific. You propably can delte most of your code from the question because it is very  distracting from your real problem. As far as I understand you have some sensor data. Please provide an copy paste example of what a sensor data can look like. And what your expectedt results from that input would look like. We can then work on how to get from the input to the output. Mabe a look at [mre] can help. Because currently your problem is neither Minimal, Complete nor Reproducible.

Comment: I´m so sorry about that, now it should be minimal. I will complete and reduce it soon :-)

Comment: A few issues to fix: a python code without correct indentation won't work. I guess your "with" is in your ds1820auslesen function, and not in that global stuff. Maybe use spaces everywhere for the forum (mixed tabs and spaces are bad). Also, your ds1820auslesen() function is called recursively with no way to exit. Lines below that won't run. Probably your .tsv is a tab separated vector, your function doesn't output anything like that. You used format twice for Temperatur. Why? Do you want to keep previous values? Opening the file in 'w' mode will delete them (use 'a', and forget the header).

Comment: Your "{:>5}\n".format('Temperatur') could be replaced by 'Temperatur'. Also, using english names is a better idea for a forum like this. Please describe what you'd like to achieve. From your code it's not clear to me.

Comment: At first, I appreciate your feedback. Should i write: " with open ( 'test.tsv', 'a') as f:" to keep the values saved in the tsv? Other things you mentioned I will be fixing soon thx.

Comment: @Nyos English names were added/edited. I want to achieve that the Temperaturevalue of my temperature Sensors were saved in tsv. So I can read out the temperature with timestamps an add some graphs in Excel

Comment: @florianvb could you please show some example data? You wrote: "The Temperature is written in a line like that: ['25.25']" How should it look like if it would be correct?

Comment: @Andreas The Temperature is written like :"['25.25', '26.00']" but It should be 25.25 next line 26.00

Comment: @florianvb could you provide a sample csv?  Is :"['25.25', '26.00']" written in the csv in the first line? if yes has it the: " or did u add them?

Comment: Why don't you put different sensors into different columns, and the next values into next line? Maybe start lines with a timestamp, so your Excel can create graphs.

Comment: @Nyos the program already wrote the temperature in the document and to put the data into different columns is exactly my problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Temperature is a list of values. If you try to put them into the csv you have to iterate over the list first, e.g.:

```
tempSensorName = []
tempSensorQuantity = 0 
tempSensorValue = [] 
programmStatus = 1
Temperature = tempSensorValue   

def ds1820einlesen():
    global tempSensorName, tempSensorQuantity, programmStatus 
def ds1820auslesen():
    global tempSensorName, tempSensorQuantity, tempSensorValue,              
            with open ( 'test.tsv', 'w') as f:
                for temperature_single in Temperature:
                    f.write ("{:>5}\n".format('Temperature'))    
                    f.write("\t{:>5}\n".format(format(temperature_single)))
                    f.write("\n")
                    f.flush()
                    f.close()
    
                    x = 0
                    ds1820auslesen()
                    print ("Sensorname and Temperaturevalue:")
                    while x < tempSensorQuantity:
                        print (tempSensorName[x] , " " ,
    tempSensorValue[x], " °C")
                            x = x + 1
    print ("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But unfortunately, there is an I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: @florianvb could you share a sample file? I mean you could just use pandas to load the csv do the transformation on a pandas.DataFrame() and then export it as .tsv again.

Comment: what do you mean with Pandas? My editor is Thonny on raspberryPi

Comment: @florianvb pandas is a library which you would need to import. The thing is it is extremly complicated to debug something if you dont have a sample data set.